# Array intersection function speed

Tags: vb.net, function, array-intersect

I've written a short function for array intersection and wanted to know why one function is faster than the other.

1)

```
Dim list2() As String 'Assume it has values'
Dim list2length As Integer = list2.length

Function newintersect(ByRef list1() As String) As String()
    Dim intersection As New ArrayList
    If (list1.Length < list2length) Then
        'use list2'
        For Each thing As String In list2
            If (Array.IndexOf(list1, thing) <> -1) Then
                intersection.Add(thing)
            End If
        Next
    Else
        'use list1'
        For Each thing As String In list1
            If (Array.IndexOf(list2, thing) <> -1) Then
                intersection.Add(thing)
            End If
        Next
    End If
    Return intersection
End Function
```

2)

```
Dim list2() As String 'Assume it has values'
Dim list2length As Integer = list2.length

Function newintersect(ByRef list1() As String) As String()
    Dim intersection As New ArrayList
    If (list1.Length > list2length) Then 'changed >'
        'use list2'
        For Each thing As String In list2
            If (Array.IndexOf(list1, thing) <> -1) Then
                intersection.Add(thing)
            End If
        Next
    Else
        'use list1'
        For Each thing As String In list1
            If (Array.IndexOf(list2, thing) <> -1) Then
                intersection.Add(thing)
            End If
        Next
    End If
    Return intersection
End Function
```

3)

```
Dim list2() As String 'Assume it has values'
Dim list2length As Integer = list2.length

Function newintersect(ByRef list1() As String) As String()
    For Each thing As String In list1
        If (Array.IndexOf(list2, thing) <> -1) Then
            intersection.Add(thing)
        End If
    Next
    Return intersection
End Function
```

So for my testcase, 1 take 65 seconds, 3 takes 63 seconds, while 2 actually takes 75 seconds. Anyone know why 3 is the fastest? And why is 1 faster than 2?

(Sorry about the poor formatting...can't seem to paste it right)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not much of a difference. Also, it doesn't seem like the methods would produce the same result, so it would be pointless to compare the performance, right?

Anyhow, the `Array.IndexOf` is not very efficient way to find items, and doesn't scale well. You should get a dramatic improvement if you use a hash key based collection as lookup instead, something like this:

```
Function newintersect(ByRef list1 As String(), ByRef list2 As String()) As String()
  Dim smaller As HashSet(Of String)
  Dim larger As String()
  If list1.Length < list2.Length Then
    smaller = New HashSet(Of String)(list1)
    larger = list2
  Else
    smaller = New HashSet(Of String)(list2)
    larger = list1
  End If
  Dim intersection As New List(Of String)
  For Each item As String In larger
    If smaller.Contains(item) Then
      intersection.Add(item)
    End If
  Next
  Return intersection.ToArray()
End Function
```

Comment: Whoa...that made a big difference...takes only 3.3 seconds as compared to 65 seconds before=D. You did make a mistake though...it shouldn't have a "not"...I'm doing an intersection..."not" would give me all those that aren't both in each list. Also this requires .net 3.5+, and while that's okay for me, is there a similar method for .net 2.0?

Comment: @user389823: Yes, the intersection... then it makes better sense. :) In framework 2.0 there is no HashSet, so you have to use a Dictionary, where the value would be unused.

Answer (score 0):

I'd expect you'd find that with different test cases you can reverse the results you had above and reach a situation where 2 is fastest and 1 & 3 are slower.

It's difficult to comment without knowing the make-up of the test case, it'll depend on the location of 'intersecting' items within the two arrays - if these tend to be close the to front on one array and closer to the end of another then the nesting order of the array iteration / IndexOf will have markedly different performance.

BTW - there are better ways of performing an intersection - sorting one or other array and performing a BinarySearch is one means - using a Dictionary(Of String, ...) or similar is another - and either would result in far better performance.

Answer (score 0):

This is from the MSDN documentation

```
    Dim id1() As Integer = {44, 26, 92, 30, 71, 38}
    Dim id2() As Integer = {39, 59, 83, 47, 26, 4, 30}

    ' Find the set intersection of the two arrays.
    Dim intersection As IEnumerable(Of Integer) = id1.Intersect(id2)

    For Each id As Integer In intersection
        Debug.WriteLine(id.ToString)
    Next
```

Comment: Would that be faster than using a hashset comparison?